# mongoDB installation in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: php, mongodb, installation, ubuntu-15.10

I'm trying to install the mongoDB driver for PHP in Ubuntu 15.10, but I'm not getting mongo in the output of `phpinfo()`.

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mongo_api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 81

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you restart your apache/nginx server?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I have fixed some typos, formatted the question in a way that should be easier to read, and added some tags, which means the question is easier to find for those that have experience in these fields and for those that might be facing the same issues. I still think this is not very precise, can you please [edit] your question and add some more details on what exactly you did? Thank you, and good luck!